# How to interpret the results from random coefficient Poisson data analysis

Tags: r, interpretation, glmm, poisson-regression

I have fitted random coefficient Poisson analysis in R. I have obtained the following results:

```
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood ['glmerMod']
Family: poisson ( log )

Formula: frequency ~ 1 + cc + ageveh + make + (1 | AREA) 

   Data: x 
      AIC       BIC    logLik  deviance 
1359.1477 1389.7370 -672.5739 1345.1477 

Random effects:
 Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 AREA   (Intercept) 1.323    1.15 

Number of obs: 584, groups: AREA, 8

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|) 

(Intercept) -0.12902    0.44432  -0.290   0.7715 
ccL          0.05656    0.12371   0.457   0.6475
agevehO      0.02136    0.09264   0.231   0.8177
make2       -0.45454    0.20632  -2.203   0.0276 *
make3       -0.31799    0.21422  -1.484   0.1377 
make4       -0.29708    0.14469  -2.053   0.0401 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
        (Intr) ccL    agevhO make2  make3
ccL      0.052         
agevehO -0.179 -0.232               
make2   -0.171 -0.007 -0.001 
make3   -0.156  0.022 -0.078  0.366     
make4   -0.300 -0.235  0.167  0.544  0.522
```

However I am unable to interpret the results.

Comment: Note that this is cross-posted from [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21943044/random-coefficient-poisson-data-analysis-in-r). Please delete the version on SO, @user40494.

Comment: Can you be more specific regarding what you need help interpreting?

Comment: The estimates of the fixed and random effects, and also how to interprete the correlation of fixed effects? How can i conclude whether male or female have more (claim) frequency? @ gung

Comment: Can you say more about your data? Eg, what are `insgenF`, `insgenM`, & `insgenM`? (The last 2 seem to be identical.) I would guess they have to do w/ sex, but there are only 2 sexes & you have 3 variables (& if they are dummies there were originally 4?).

Comment: insgenF represents female and insgenM represents male.There are 2 variables.But when i fitted in R, it resulted into three which made me confused. @gung

Comment: You're right, that makes no sense. Moreover, you cannot include both male and female in the same model, as not-male perfectly predicts female. Can you provide your code & some sample data that allows people to reproduce your results?

Comment: Previously my data was organised as follows:                         
79 2010 0 M
79 2011 0 M
79 2012 0 M
79 2013 0 M
80 2009 0 M
80 2010 0 M
80 2011 1 M
80 2012 0 M
80 2013 0 M
82 2009 0 F
82 2010 0 F
82 2011 0 F
82 2012 1 F
82 2013 0 F
83 2009 0 F
83 2010 0 F
83 2011 0 F
83 2012 0 F
83 2013 1 F

Comment: where 79,80,1,82,83 are ID and respective claim frequency for a period of 5 years (2009-2013) and M and F are gender. However i reorganised my data and sum the frequency for all individuals. Then i obtained the result as follows:

Comment: Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood ['glmerMod']
Family: poisson ( log )
Formula: frequency ~ 1 + insgen + (1 | ID) 
   Data: Panel 

      AIC       BIC    logLik   deviance 
1596.6541   1609.7638 -795.3271 1590.6541 
Random effects:
 Groups Name        Variance  Std.Dev. 
 ID     (Intercept) 1.893e-10 1.376e-05
Number of obs: 584, groups: ID, 584
Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)  0.07914    0.07372   1.073    0.283
insgenM      0.04560    0.08699   0.524    0.600
Correlation of Fixed Effects:
        (Intr)
insgenM -0.847 @gung

Comment: instead of answering in comments, could you edit your Q to add this material in a more readable format?

Comment: okay. I have re asked the question @gung

Comment: I have refitted my model i included area as my random effect and included age cc and make of vehicle as predictors. Can you please help me in interpreting it now? Thanks @gung